# Extracting "working day + 1" and distributing amounts accordingly

Tags: database, teradata

I have one table (let's call it Table_A) which contains "due_date column", "amount", and "bank_institute".
There is another table (lookup table) which contains columns "bank_institute", and "clearing_house".
In the lookup table internal as well as external bank institutes are assigned to one clearing house. For example: clearing house CH1 has external bank institutes (from other banks) BI1, BI2... and also it has INTERNAL bank institutes (form the clearing house) BI_CH1, BI_CH2...
Another example - if you have a company and you say: I want to get all the money from customers in Bank of America, than clearing house is "Bank of America" and every payment to Bank of America subsidiaries are "internal bank institus", whereas for example Bank of England is connected with "Bank of America"  - that is external bank institute.
As said, these relationships are modelled in the lookup table.

Table_A has due_date column. But it is so arranged that some banks will retrieve money on the due_date, and some on due_date + 1. Here "+1" means "the following working day".

The problem and my question is: how can I identify "due_date + 1" i.e. "due date + the following working day" in order to predict how money I will get in the following 120 working days?

P.S. I have a table from which I can extract the next 120 WORKING days. The problem is - I have no idea on how to map "working_day + 1" to get the right amounts.

Database flavor: Teradata

Comment: How can you define a "Working day"? Is it in all cases Monday to Friday or is there a more complex model behind it? And: From the table where you can extract the next 120 Working Days, can you also the next working day? AND: Can you give us the `create table`source, too. It would help to understand your model better and easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is quite confusing :-) Some more details about the rules and example rows plus the expected result will be nice to have.

If "working day" simply means next monday when the day is saturday or sunday then it will be easy.

But "working day" might be much more complex than monday to friday (especially in a banking environment). The easiest way is your (hopefully) existing calendar table, there probably will be a working_day indicator column. You need to add a new DATE column and update it to next working day based on the rules of your business. This is a one-time setup process and then you can easily join to the calendar.

Edit: 
I just read your P.S., what is this table, a calendar or just a list of dates?

Anyway, you can use this to construct the list of next_working_days on-the-fly:

```
SELECT
   calendar_date,
   working_day, 
   MIN(working_day) 
   OVER (ORDER BY calendar_date DESC 
         RESET WHEN working_day IS NOT NULL 
         ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS next_working_day
FROM sys_calendar.CALENDAR 
LEFT JOIN working_days_table ON calendar_date = working_day
WHERE calendar_date BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(working_day) FROM working_days_table)
                        AND (SELECT MAX(working_day) FROM working_days_table);
```